# Selenium Python. Сложный поиск

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Есть несколько элементов которые имеют двойное описание с наличием ссылки: `<a class="name-link" href="ССЫЛКА">AAA</a>` и `<a class="name-link" href="ССЫЛКА">BBB/CCC/DDD</a>`
Цель: Среди схожих описаний типа AAA, найти по второму описанию, например, ССС
Мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

A = "AAA"
B = "CCC"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Program Files\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("ССЫЛКА НА СТРАНИЦУ С ЭЛЕМЕНТАМИ")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(A) and driver.find_element_by_link_text(B)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как составить сложную цепочку поиска с необходимыми условиями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно найти один элемент с уникальным наличием двух нужных аргументов?
Вам нужно найти соседний элемент с определённым аргументом по определённому аргументу соседа?
Или вам нужно найти несколько элементов у одних из который будет один аргумент, у других другой?

Если по первому варианту вопроса, то напишите XPath с двумя атрибутами равными `A` и `B` соответственной и ищите такой объект одним `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Если дадите хотя-бы пример структуры вашего html, то это сразу упростит задачу))

---

Я всё равно не понял что именно вам нужно)))) Но догадываюсь что именно это:

Согласно вашего примера:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <h1>
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка1">Square</a>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка1">Blue</a>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <div>
        <h1>
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка2">Square</a>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка2">Black</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Вам нужно найти элемент с текстовым блоком равным 'Black', если рядом (по определённой структуре) есть сосед с текстом 'Square' (или наоборот Square с соседом Black). И так же согласно структуре, у двух этих элементов общий предок `div`.
Вот так это можно решить с помощью xpath:

```
//*[text()='Square']/ancestor::div//*[text()='Black']
```

Этот xpath словами - брузер, дружище, верни мне **Black** если у *общего предка* **div** будет *потомок* **Square**, но ***других не нужно***!

Подробнее о коде, но начнём с конца:

`//*[text()='Black']` - ищем целевой элемент с текстом `'Black'` в непонятной (`//*`) структуре

`ancestor::div` - с предком `div`, но неизвестным количеством шагов до него (`ancestor::`)

`//*[text()='Square']` - с потомком с текстом `'Square'` в такой-же непонятной структуре (`//*`)

И потом просим WebDriver сделать это для нас))):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[text()='Square']/ancestor::div//*[text()='Black'])
```

Почему xpath, а не текст? Так мы, помимо указания конкретного элемента, ещё и указываем приблизительную структуру документа, и поиск происходит одной командой)

Надеюсь именно это вам и нужно было)))

---

**UPD2**

Если вам нужно найти элемент у которого есть сосед 'Black', то вам поможет вот такой xpath:

```
//*[text()='Black']/ancestor::div//*/a[text()!='Black']
```

Запрос с таким xpath вернёт два элемента - `Square` и `Triangle` у которых есть сосед `Black`

И вы должны понимать, что `.find_element_by_xpath()` вернёт только ПЕРВОЕ попадание в критерий, если вам нужны ВСЕ элементы подходящие под критерии то - `.find_elements_by_xpath()`.

Comment: `<article>
<div>
<h1>
<a class="name-link" href="ссылка1">Square</a>
</h1>
<p>
<a class="name-link" href="ссылка1">Blue</a>
</div>
</article>
<article>
<div>
<h1>
<a class="name-link" href="ссылка2">Square</a>
</h1>
<p>
<a class="name-link" href="ссылка2">Black</a>
</div>
</article>`
Мне нужно среди 2 элементов найти Square Black, для этого я использую `driver.find_element_by_link_text()` и хотел бы узнать каким ещё способом я могу это сделать

Comment: Я попробовал ваш метод, но он всё ещё не работает. Так как если имеется третий элемент, например  
<article>  
    <div>  
        <h1>  
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка3">Triangle</a>  
        </h1>  
        <p>  
            <a class="name-link" href="ссылка3">Black</a>  
    </div>  
</article>  
и после выполняется такой код:  
`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Square']/ancestor::div//*[text()='Black']")`  
для проверки выполняется  
`element.click()`  
и в итоге выводится Square Black

Comment: Да, он и будет выводить именно Black Square потому что запрос именно на них. Я так понял вам нужен был именно такой вариант. А вам нужны все элементы с соседом Black?

Comment: Опечатка, извиняюсь. Эта команда выводит Triangle Black

Comment: Я добавил вариант, он может быть вашим)))